# Combine .txt files and add part of file name as new column value

Tags: r, string, loops, multiple-columns, filenames

I am combining a number of files that are essentially .txt files, though called .sta.
I've used the following code to combine them after having trouble with base R `apply` and `dplyr` `lapply`:

```
library(plyr)
myfiles <-  list.files(path="LDI files", pattern ="*.sta", full.names = TRUE) 
dat_tab <- ldply(myfiles, read.table, header= TRUE, sep = "\t",  skip = 5)
```

I want to add a column which has values which are part of the file names. File name examples are **"GFREX28-00-1"** and "**GFREX1534-00-1"** . I want to keep the digits immediately after GFREX, before the first dash -.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `dat_tab <- sapply(myfiles, read.table, header= TRUE, sep = "\t",  skip = 5, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)`, followed by `dplyr::bind_rows(dat_tab, .id = "file")`. This reads in the tables as a named list (where the names equal the filenames), and then binds them together, storing these names in a new column called "file".

Comment: Keeping only those digits can be done via `names(dat_tab) <- stringr::str_extract(names(dat_tab), "(?<=GFREX)\\d+")` just after `dat_tab` is created, before the `bind_rows` line.

Comment: Thanks. When I used ```dplyr::bind_rows(dat_tab, .id = "file")``` I got the error ```Column `R..Kohm.` can't be converted from numeric to factor```.

Comment: So I tried ```dplyr::bind_rows(mutate_all(dat_tab, as.numeric), .id = "file")``` and got error ```no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "list"```

Comment: This worked ```dat_tab <- sapply(myfiles, read.table, header= TRUE, sep = "\t", skip = 5, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
names(dat_tab) <- stringr::str_extract(names(dat_tab), "(?<=GFREX)\\d+")  
binded1 = rbindlist(dat_tab, idcol = "files")```. Can you explain how the ```names``` function works and how it knows to put the names in the new id column

Comment: Glad you figured it out! The `names` function extracts (or assigns) names to the `dat_tab` list. The `rbindlist` (or `bind_rows`) function does not only bind the elements of the list together into one big dataframe, it also reads those names and puts them in a column you specify (in this case "files"). The `"(?<=GFREX)\\d+"` part is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that searches for GFREX and extracts all digits (`\\d+`) that follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. I provide a tentative answer. The idea is to assign a new column to the data.frame before returning it.

```
filepaths <-  list.files(path="LDI files", pattern ="*.sta", 
                          full.names = TRUE)
filesnames <-  list.files(path="LDI files", pattern ="*.sta", 
                          full.names = FALSE) 

dat_tab <- lapply(1:length(filepaths), function(i) {
    df <-  read.table(filepaths[i] header= TRUE, sep = "\t",  skip = 5)
             df$fn <- gsub("GFREX","",filesnames[i])
    df
})
```